# How to get input fields and submit button same size

Tags: html, css

I'm new to this site and a beginner at html and css.  I'm working on a personal project for practice and the design calls for both the input box and submit button to be a height of 55px and a width of 320 px.  Both of these include a 2px border and a 15px padding.  I'm not sure why my current code is not producing the same sizes.  The input button is clearly smaller (both width and height) than the input boxes.

Any help would be appreciated.

```css
body {
  background-color: blue;
}

/* LOGO */

.logo img {
  height: 35px;
  padding: 50px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* FORM */

.form {
  background-color: white;
  width: 400px;
  height: 500px;
  padding: 40px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

h1 {
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px;
}
input[type='email'],
input[type='password'],
button[type='submit']{
  height: 38px;
  width: 303px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px auto;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;

}

button {
  background-color: green;
}

span {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">
  <img src="images/logo.png" alt="AnalogSea logo">
</div>

<div class="form">
  <h1>Sign up</h1>
  <form action="/signup" method="post" class="form_section">
    <label class="email button_size" for="email" required>Email</label><br>
    <input placeholder="foo@bar.com" type="email" name="email" id="email"><br>
    <label class="email button_size" for="password" required>Password</label><br>
    <input placeholder="1234passw0rd" type="password" name="password"><br>
    <button type="submit"><span>Sign Up</span></button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: `<span>Sign Up</span>`, or any HTML inside a button is a no, no. Remember, `<button type='submit'>Sign Up</button>` is just like `<input type='submit' value='Sign Up' />`.

Comment: Thanks for the input,  I didn't know that.  Like I said, I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 4):

The reason it's happening is the way the `box-model` is rendered in browsers. In your example, the padding is what is causing the issue. For the button, the padding and border is *included* in the `303px`, so the button is a total of `303px` wide. For the `<input>` elements, the padding and border is *added* to the total width, giving it a width of `337px`.

To fix this you can go about it a couple ways. You can reset the `box-sizing` (the property in CSS that handles this) globally like:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box }
```

Or you can add that to just the `<input>` elements.

```
input[type="whatever"] { box-sizing: border-box }
```

I personally do it globally as a reset, to make things consistent. That's a my preference.

If you do this, you'll have to readjust the `height` on your elements to `68px`, because now the padding will be considered as part of the `height` property, not added to it.

Here's some reading on the box-model: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Here's some reading on the `box-sizing` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Hope this helps!

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  Exactly the type of explanation I was looking for!  Thanks so much for taking the time to answer my question!

Answer (score 0):

I would change:

```
<button type="submit"><span>Sign Up</span></button>
```

to

```
<input type='submit' value='Sign Up' />
```

then alter your CSS. This solution is more backward compatible, as well.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Just add `* { box-sizing: border-box }`

Comment: I'm the one that voted you up. That will change them all, though, and it's CSS3.